# Separating the "for" loop into small methods- what is the best performance option? (C#)

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, refactoring, cycle

What is better in terms of speed and performance?

The cycle in one place, and then in each cycle step, call all the necessary methods:

```
for(int i = 0, i < array.Length, i++){
    MethodA (i);
    MethodB (i);
    MethodC (i);
}

void MethodA (int i) {
    //do something
}

void MethodB (int i) {
    //do something
}

void MethodC (int i) {
    //do something
}
```

Duplicate the loop in each method:

```
void MethodA () {
    for(int i = 0, i < array.Length, i++){
        //do something
    }
}
void MethodB () {
    for(int i = 0, i < array.Length, i++){
        //do something
    }
}
void MethodC () {
    for(int i = 0, i < array.Length, i++){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Or sequentially invoke the next method from the previous one, along with the transfer of the loop variable:

```
void MethodA () {
    for(int i = 0, i < array.Length, i++){
        //do something
        MethodB (i);
    }
}

void MethodB (int i) {
    //do something
    MethodC (i);
}

void MethodC (int i) {
    //do something
}
```

If this is important, the code is created for Unity.

Comment: All three are the same, only the order of execution changes. The first one is the easiest to read. Therefore I would go for it.

Comment: Examples 1 & 2 are not functionally equivalent; example 1 interleaves the three methods, whereas example 2 does not (it does all A, then all B, then all C). Does it make sense to compare the non-functional performance when they are not functionally the same?

Comment: They are only functionally different if there is a dependency between the methods - if they are entire independent, then yes, it makes sense.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, any difference between these approaches will be small enough to be unmeasurable. However, since you mention it's for Unity, there's a chance that tiny performance differences really will matter in your case. There are too many possible variables to say which one will be fastest just by looking at it. For example, if your array is long then option 1 might benefit better from your hardware's caching mechanism. The best advice I can give is to benchmark.

Comment: If you have three horses and want to know which is fastest, [race your horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Don't describe your horses on the internet and ask people for their opinions.

Comment: @DourHighArch Erics website domain seems to be for sale and I don't think it is intentional. :o

Comment: Generally speaking, looping 3 times over a sequence is slower than looping once, calling 3 methods is slower than calling one, indexing an array 3 times is slower indexing once, etc.. Specifically, it depends, on specifics.